# What does "to be Surgeon to the Swallow, Captain Abraham Pannell Commander" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Soon after my Return from Leyden, I was recommended by my
> good Master Mr Bates, **to be Surgeon to the Swallow, Captain
> Abraham Pannell Commander**; with whom I continued three Years
> and a half, making a Voyage or two into the Levant, and some
> other Parts.

Does it mean: Captain Abraham Pannell was the commander of a ship named Swallow?

Source: *Gulliver's Travels*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does mean tha Abraham Pannell was the commander of a ship name "Swallow", which by the way was suggested in the books to be a slave-trading ship.